# how to write Arabic data to pdf using iText in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am creating pdf from html string using iText in java folloing is my code

```
   try {    
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);  
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance
               (document, new FileOutputStream("d://itextpdf.pdf"));       
    document.open();

    XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

 String str = "<html><head></head><body>"+
                 "<table border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' id='' class=''>" +
                 "<tr><th> Sr.No.</th><th>Currency Id</th><th>Code</th><th>Name</th>" +
                 "<tr><td align='center'>1</td><td align='center'>1</td>"+
                 "<td align='center'>100</td>"+
                 "<td align='center'>الرياض (رويترز)</td></tr>" +
                 "</table></body></html>"
   worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, 
             new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8")))) ;
   document.close();
}catch(Exception e){ }
```

but it can not show Arabic data in generated pdf. what should i do? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can set font before writing it.
Example

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
Font font = new Font(bf, 14);
```